# Subtracting two following addresses that containing ints returns 1 and not 4 as expected

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p = a;
    int *q = p++;
    int b = p-q;
    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

`p` is pointing on the `2` and `q` is pointing to the `1`.
I know that Integer takes `4` bytes in the memory, so correct me if I am wrong, but for example if the address of `a[0]` is `1000`, then the address of `a[1]` will be `1004`

if so, why does subtracting these addresses give us `1` and not `4`?

Comment: Because that's how the pointer arithmetic is defined. It's useful so that pointer arithmetic can behave equivalently to array indexing. You should try to look up this topic with a search engine.

Comment: Also, the `int` type *does not*, in C, take up *any specific* amount of memory. It depends on the platform.

Comment: You are incorrect to assume that an integer takes 4 bytes in memory.  On many platforms that is true, but not all.

Comment: Note that `*(p+1)` is the same as `p[1]`. What do they have in common? Both know the size of the data type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have clearly misunderstood how pointer arithmetic works.

Consider this:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p = a;
p = p + 1;
```

Now where do you expect `p` to point? At `2`, i.e. `at a[1]`? Or did you expect it to point in the middle of `1`, i.e. in the middle of `a[0]`?

The answer is that `p` points to `a[1]`.

Now consider

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p = a;
int *q = a;
p = p + 1;
int b = p-q;
```

and do some simple substitution:

```
int b = p-q;
```

since

```
p is a + 1
q = a
```

we get

```
int b = (a + 1) - a;
```

which is

```
int b = 1;
```

So obviously the result is 1.

Answer (score 0):

From C11 Standard#6.5.6p9 *[emphasis added]*

> **When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object**, or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements**. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and **its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t** defined in the <stddef.h> header. ....

From [this](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx4a.html):

> The subscript which specifies a single element of an array is simply an integer expression in square brackets.

```
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p = a;
    int *q = p++;
```

Both pointer `p` and `q` pointing to elements of same array object i.e. array `a`. Pointer `p` is pointing to second element of array `a`, which is `a[1]` (subscript is `1`) and pointer `q` is pointing to first element of array `a`, which is `a[0]` (subscript is `0`).

The result of `p - q` is `1 - 0` which is equal to `1`. Hence, you are getting output `1`.

Ideally, the type of `b` should be `ptrdiff_t` and provide `%td` format specifier to `printf()` for `b`:

```
    ptrdiff_t b = p - q;
    printf("%td", b);
```